# git p4 port error leads to fail

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I am trying to implement git p4 for some developers so they can be using Perforce instead of git, but we still need git to push things later on.  While trying to do the initial clone of the Perforce depot path, I am getting the following error:

Perforce client error:
     Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT
     TCP connect to perforce:1666
     nodename nor servname provided, or not known

When I do a p4 info, everything looks good.  I have looked around and see lots of references to creating a .perforce or .p4settings file, but everyone has a different idea of where to put it, how to pass it to git and what to call it.  I've tried a few permutations of it in different places and can't get it going.  Any ideas of where I am going wrong and how exactly I need to setup the .whatever file if that is my problem?  I'm on Mavericks OS.

Thank you,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

P4PORT notoriously does not work. Use:

```
P4HOST=machine:1234
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  Our server admin changed it a while back to 1667, but now it's 1666 and p4 crazily keeps trying 1667... no idea where this setting is coming from as p4 info is correct and p4 works fine.